# how MVVM model is related with WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I am trying to create sample WPF application with MVVM architecture. I have model which has `Employee` class {DTO} with corresponding View and viewmodel.

Similarly i have created WCF service which has reference from WPF application to make make use of model{Employee} that i have earlier created.

My scenario is i have to get list of all Employees from service.
For that code is as follows

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    EmployeeData EmpData = new EmployeeData();

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> loadAllEmployees()
    {

        return EmpData.LoadAllEmployees();
    }
```

The  is reference from model class of MVVM.
Code to load all Employees is as below EmployeeService is my wcf service

```
       public ObservableCollection<Employee> EmployeeList
    {
        get 
        {
            return employeeList;             
        }
        set
        {
            employeeList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("EmployeeList");
        }

      EmployeeService.Service1Client EmpService = new EmployeeService.Service1Client();
      EmployeeList = EmpService.loadAllEmployees();
```

But here am facing Error as

```
Cannot Implicitly convert type System.Collections.Object.ObservableCollection<WPF_TestProj.EmployeeService.Employee> to System.Collections.Object.ObservableCollection<WPF_TestProj.Model.Employee>
```

If delcare `EmployeeList` as list of `EmployeeService.Employee` this wont come, but my service dont have `Employee` Class .

Please suggest me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the `Employee` in a shared Library so that both WCF and WPF can reference to and use the same `Employee` class.

Comment: There is no need for a shared library when using WCF. If a WCF service exposes a complex type, in this case Employee, then when a Service Reference is made within WPF the Employee type will be created within the WPF project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referencing the WCF using a Service Reference? If so, then you don't need to reference the service library directly as any types exposed by the service will be created as part of the service proxy within the WPF application. If you are referencing the library directly, then its possible that the call to the service method is returning the model defined as part of the Service Reference, but your property is using the type defined directly within the service library.